# collect objects in array who's keys match a map key, value

Tags: javascript, node.js

My issue is I have an array of objects and a map of key, values that exist multiple times in the objects in that array. My end goal is a new array of objects in the old array that match both the key and value of the map.

```
for example:
map: {{"1234", "abcd"},{"4567","efgh"}}

array: [
{key: "1234", value1: "abcd"}, 
{key: "1234", value1: "jhgfg"}, 
{key: "4567", value1: "efgh"}, 
{key: "4567", value1: "poiu"}]

goal: [
{key: "1234", value1: "abcd"}, 
{key: "4567", value1: "efgh"}]
```

I just cant get the syntax. Here is the code i was thinking would work but isnt, since its adding all objects regardless:

```
for (let [key, value] of dataMap.entries()) {
        for (var data in dataIn) {
          var keep = dataIn[data];
          if (keep.key === key && keep.timestamp === value) {
            endData.push(keep);
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: The objects in your `map` structure are invalid. Please provide runnable data

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you need to convert the object into an array of objects. You can do it like that:

```js
const mapOfKeysAndValues = {
  "1234": "abcd",
  "4567": "efgh"
}

const keyValuePairs = Object.entries(mapOfKeysAndValues).map(pair => ({
  [pair[0]]: pair[1]
}))

console.log(keyValuePairs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can do this with a simple Array#filter()

```js
const map = {
  "1234": "abcd",
  "4567": "efgh"
},
arr= [
{key: "1234", value1: "abcd"}, 
{key: "1234", value1: "jhgfg"}, 
{key: "4567", value1: "efgh"}, 
{key: "4567", value1: "poiu"}];

const res = arr.filter(o => map[o.key] === o.value1)

console.log(res)
```